# Generate android buttons with while loop in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I'm lost here. I need to read the files in a directory and make buttons from them when an app starts. I have to use a while loop, and I have to update the UI. I've tried for quite a while to run a runnable and have only the code inside the loop run in the UI thread. I'm relatively new to android, but this seemed simple enough.

This code is what I have right now. It throws no errors or warnings, but it doesn't do anything. I know the button making code works because the "add button" button makes buttons correctly. I have no idea why it isn't working.
   (This runs in OnCreate)

```
Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp/");
        File[] filearray = f.listFiles();
        int amount = filearray.length;
        final String[] files = new String[amount];
        int count = 0;
        while (count != amount) {
            files[count] = filearray[count].toString();
            count += 1;
        }
        int times = files.length;
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter != times) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Button making code
                }
            });
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
};
Thread thread = new Thread(aRunnable);
thread.start();
```

Comment: Can you define "it isn't working"? You say the "button making code" works and you have no errors or warnings so what is/isn't happening?

Comment: The app starts and works perfectly except no buttons are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that you're trying to have a list of buttons based on some array. It seems that is a job for a ListView and a custom array adapter. I believe you should google some examples on it (there're billions around the internet, it's a fairly basic android pattern).

and while you're in the learning process, don't forget to check how to use `for()` in Java, all those `while` loops are just so ugly.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your existing code is that everything in the `run()` method gets run on a background thread, not the main (sometimes called the *UI*) thread.

This is where you're creating your handler object:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
```

This is not correct.  You need to create (instantiate) the `Handler` on the main thread, if using the default constructor.  From [the Handler docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler%28%29):

> `public Handler ()` Added in API level 1
>
> Default constructor **associates this handler with the Looper for the
>   current thread**. If this thread does not have a looper, this handler
>   won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.

So, a simple fix is simply to move that line of code earlier, into a place that you know is run on the main thread.  [For example, in `Activity#onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
   super.onCreate(b);

   handler = new Handler();
}
```

where `handler` is changed to be a member variable:

```
private Handler handler;
```

Also, just remove your `Looper` calls.

[See this article for more on Handler](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_handler).

### Other Options

Another option would be to avoid using `Handler` at all, and get famliar with the [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  I personally think that's easier for new developers to use.  The vogella.com link I showed also has good information on `AsyncTask`.

Yet one more option would be to avoid `Handler` and use the [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method in your `Activity` to add your buttons.